# Multiplying bl by 8

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to multiply the register bl by 8 and store the result in bl. However when I run:

```
mov bl,1
mov al,8
mul bl
```

bl still equals 1, not 8. I vaguely remember something about the value moving into bx or ax or something...could someone give a helping hand? Thanks!!

Wanted behavior:

```
bl*=8
```

Comment: When in doubt consult the instruction set reference. `mul bl` produces result in `ax`. Also, to multiply by powers of 2, you normally use shifts. All you need is `shl bl, 3`.

Comment: If you single-step with a debugger that highlights which register(s) changed after the last instruction, you'll have a much easier time catching mistakes like this.  See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying by 8 is easiest done through shifting left 3 times:

```
shl bl, 3
```

To correct the code you wrote yourself you only need to add a single `mov`:

```
mov bl, 1
mov al, 8
mul bl       ;AL * BL --> AX
mov bl, al
```

Comment: or, `imul ebx, ebx, 8` does (signed multiply) ebx = ebx * 8.  This is the 3-operand non-destructive form: `imul r32, r/m32, imm8`, also available with an `imm32`.  Not available in 8-bit operand size, or for unsigned mul.